# Как подключить статическую библиотеку собранную в Visual Studio для cmake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

начал делать проект, в котором хорошо бы использовать некоторые методы из прошлых проектов. Поэтому решил собрать с прошлого проекта статическую библиотеку. Я собрал ее и в другом проекте в Visual Studio я ее подключил и все работает замечательно. Но вот мне надо использовать Cmake, так как проект делается на Qt. И я столкнулся с тем что не знаю как подключить свою библиотеку. Пробовал через target_link_libraries, но при сборке приложения получаю ошибку линковки, что библиотеку не может найти. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и может подсказать как ее решить?
CmakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Easy VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(ips "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libmymath")


#================                            ================#
get_filename_component(Qt_ROOT_DIR ${Qt6_DIR} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(Qt_ROOT_DIR ${Qt_ROOT_DIR} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(Qt_ROOT_DIR ${Qt_ROOT_DIR} DIRECTORY)
#============================================================#

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Widgets CONFIG)

qt_add_resources(RESOURCES resource.qrc)

qt_add_executable(appEasy WIN32
  main.cpp
  ${RESOURCES}
)

qt_add_qml_module(appEasy
    URI Easy
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES main.qml
    QML_FILES WindowInfo.qml
    SOURCES version.h
    SOURCES iver.h iver.cpp
    QML_FILES
    SOURCES
    SOURCES hiver.h hiver.cpp
    SOURCES back.h back.cpp
)

#================== Qt6                        ==================#
    add_custom_command(TARGET appEasy POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/bin"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:appEasy>)

            add_custom_command(TARGET appEasy POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/lib"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:appEasy>)

    add_custom_command(TARGET appEasy POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/modules"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:appEasy>)

    add_custom_command(TARGET appEasy POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/plugins"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:appEasy>)

    add_custom_command(TARGET appEasy POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${Qt_ROOT_DIR}/qml"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:appEasy>)
#================================================= =============#
target_link_libraries(appEasy
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets)

#============================ ips ============================#
message(${ips})
include_directories(${ips}/include/libIP/C)
include_directories(${ips}/include/libIP/CPP)
target_link_libraries(appEasy PRIVATE Easy/libmymath/lib/x64/FullLib)
```

Ошибка Fatal error LNK1104:  не удается открыть файл "Easy/libmymath/lib/x64/FullLib"

Comment: Когда в команде `target_link_libraries` указываете путь, то это должен быть **абсолютный** путь к **файлу**.